# angular js site just stopped working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

below is my entire angular.js index page which as of five minutes ago was working as intended displaying the 5 seperate entries i have in my database in the list i have setup. After a restart of chrome it is no longer working and i am getting the following error: Error: [$interpolate:noconcat](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$interpolate/noconcat?p0=%7B%7BmyUrl%7D%7D)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<script 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">
</script>
<style>
    .posts {
        margin: 0 0 2em 0;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        width: 50em;
    }
    .posts li {
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #EEE;
        margin: .5em;
        padding: .3em 0;
        height: 20em;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
    .posts .text {
        position: relative;
        top: -3px;
    }
</style>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="postsCtrl">
    <h1>GWAT Websites and Designs</h1>

    <ul class="posts">
        <li *ng-repeat="post in names.retRows">
            {{post.title}}<br>
            {{post.pBody}}<br>
            {{post.category}}<br>
            <iframe ng-src={{myUrl}})></iframe><br><br>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('postsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.myUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('https://www.angularjs.org');
    $scope.changeIt = function (changUrl) {
        $scope.myUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('changUrl');
    }
    $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8081/process_get")
    .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data;});
});

</script>
```

I know from console that my http get is still returning an appropriate json that hasnt changed. any help in regards to this error or some small mistake im missing would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo error.Also, `ng-src` value need to wrap around double quotes

change `<iframe ng-src={{myUrl}})></iframe><br><br>`

to `<iframe ng-src="{{myUrl}}"></iframe><br><br>`

also, inject the `$sce` to the controller

Demo

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('postsCtrl', function($scope, $http,$sce) {
    $scope.myUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('https://www.angularjs.org');
    $scope.changeIt = function (changUrl) {
        $scope.myUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('changUrl');
    }
    $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8081/process_get")
    .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data;});
})
```

```css
.posts {
        margin: 0 0 2em 0;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        width: 50em;
    }
    .posts li {
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #EEE;
        margin: .5em;
        padding: .3em 0;
        height: 20em;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
    .posts .text {
        position: relative;
        top: -3px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">
</script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="postsCtrl">
  <h1>GWAT Websites and Designs</h1>

  <ul class="posts">
      <li *ng-repeat="post in names.retRows">
          {{post.title}}<br>
          {{post.pBody}}<br>
          {{post.category}}<br>
          <iframe ng-src="{{myUrl}}"></iframe><br><br>
      </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: this fixes the issue with the error i was getting but it is no longer looping through ng-repeat is there any notable reason for this in the html i dont think it could be the node.js file i am running as this has not changed but i can add that if necessary

Comment: post the json array

Comment: nvm for some reason i must have changed something that stopped the need for me to use names.retRows and instead just need names now